# Is this sentence correct with commas, or do I need to put more somewhere?

Tags: commas, transcription

Okay, profit shifting to tax havens is a significant thing, although it's not a higher percent because if the ability to globalize where profits are reported was unlimited, then we wouldn't have seen a decline in corporate tax receipts after the Trump Tax Cut.

**This is a sentence I transcribed.**

The speaker had a small pause after "because" and "unlimited", so I'm not sure if that part of the sentence should be separated with commas. I am not sure if "Okay" should be its own sentence because the speaker took a slightly longer break after saying "okay" (like a second).

Comment: As presented, this looks like Off Topic proofreading. Was there any particular comma you think *shouldn't* be there? Or some specific position where you think perhaps you *should* have included a comma? If so, ***why**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The speaker had a small pause after "because" and "unlimited", so I'm not sure if that part of the sentence should be separated with commas.
I am not sure if "Okay" should be its own sentence because the speaker took a slightly longer break after saying "okay" (like a second).

Comment: @matacar Are you trying to represent how the speaker spoke, or are you trying to find your own rhythm to speak in? If the former, then we really can't answer you because we haven't heard the recording.

Comment: @matacar this is spoken English, and so it has a natural flow that is somewhat different to the way that you would write it. If I were writing something like this and it proved impractical to divide that sentence up, I would, as you suggest, put a comma after **because**.

Comment: What you say there about "speaker had a small pause" is ***very important information*** that should really be included in the question text itself, not buried down here in a comment. Note that most *linguists* will tell you that the ***only*** reason for using commas in writing is to reflect pauses in speech. Most *grammarians*, on the other hand, will focus on "syntactic" justifications for their preferred orthography.

Comment: (I will retract my "proofreading" closevote if you edit the question as suggested above.)

Comment: @JavaLatte "Sometimes speakers stutter, make unnecessary pauses, and ticks that should be ignored to make an easy to understand point." This is written in the style guide for transcribing. However, I still need to reach out to anyone I can for help.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I added the question from my comment.

Comment: *Sometimes speakers stutter, make unnecessary **...** pauses, and [blah blah].* ***That's*** how you indicate orthographically that the speaker paused for some "non-syntactic" reason (he was deliberating over whether to use the word ***pause***, or ***hesitate***, perhaps). But oftentimes there's no *point* in faithfully reproducing something like that - figuratively speaking, your written transcription is probably supposed to "paint a picture", rather than "take a photograph".